# Google Sheet to Calendar script for creating editorial calendar / changing variable names

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I would like to have a Google Sheet that syncs with a Google Calendar to help keep my editorial calendar more organized. I've found some [great code online](https://github.com/Davepar/gcalendarsync/blob/master/gcalendarsync.js) that does 90% of what I need, but the code is primarily for event management. All of my entries will be all-day events, so I don't really need the start and end time feature.

Here is what I would like to accomplish:

- Rename the 'Start Time' column to 'Date'
- Delete the 'End Time' column
- Default all entries to all-day events

The original developer was kind enough to include a [spreadsheet template](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b0BBnmoDT4uDbN0pYsH--mpasFR45QlgNMTwUH-7MqU/edit#gid=0).

I tried changing the name of column C on the spreadsheet to **Date** and then updating `var titleRow` in row 10, but I get the following error message:

> Spreadsheet must have Title, Start Time, End Time, All Day Event, and Id columns

Any suggestions on how to correct the error? What about defaulting to all-day events? Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [**Calendar Service**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/)

> - [`createAllDayEvent(title, date)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createalldayeventtitle-date)
>
>   - Creates a new all-day event.
> - [`createAllDayEvent(title, date, options)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createalldayeventtitle-date-options)
>
>   - Creates a new all-day event.(with options)
> - [`createAllDayEventSeries(title, startDate, recurrence)`](http://createAllDayEventSeries(title,%20startDate,%20recurrence,%20options))
>
>   - Creates a new all-day event series.
> - [`createAllDayEventSeries(title, startDate, recurrence, options)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createalldayeventseriestitle-startdate-recurrence-options)
> - Creates a new all-day event series.(with options)

---

**Code sample for all-day events series(with options)**

```
 // Creates an event series for a no-meetings day, taking place every Wednesday in 2013.
 var eventSeries = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createAllDayEventSeries('No Meetings',
     new Date('January 2, 2013 03:00:00 PM EST'),
     CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule()
         .onlyOnWeekday(CalendarApp.Weekday.WEDNESDAY)
         .until(new Date('January 1, 2014')),
     {guests: 'everyone@example.com'});
 Logger.log('Event Series ID: ' + eventSeries.getId());
```

Creating an event as a all day event, we use createAllDayEvent / createAllDayEventSeries function. For the series it will use the [recurrence](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-recurrence) and some additional parameters like [location, description, guest, sendInvites](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createalldayeventtitle-date-options).

Hope this helps